# Outlook removing <br>?

Tags: email, outlook

I have some simple code that adds a line break in certain inboxes and viewports.

This is the jist, but Outlook seems to be ignoring it completely. Any clue?

```
 <style>
 .br-break {display: none;}

 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .br-break {display: block!important;}

 }
 </style>

 <td>
 Text<br class="br-break">Text
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<br>` element is fully supported by Outlook and its rendering engine. Try to use it as a separate element on the page. But the `line-break` and `dislay` CSS properties are not supported. The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies, read more about that in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.